# What does it mean to install a conda package in development mode?

Tags: conda, conda-build

I was looking around Conda's documentation and I found this: https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda-build/en/latest/resources/commands/conda-develop.html?highlight=develop

It explains how to install a package in development mode but it doesn't seem to explain what that actually means and how it differs from a normal install.

Answer (score 3):

First, note that that documentation is for `conda-build` and not `conda` (which has [separate documentation](https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/index.html)).  The former is for developing Conda-deliverable packages; the latter is for managing virtual environments.

Apparently, `conda develop` will build a package in place and only install it through a link placed in `site-packages` (specifically adding the path to the package into the  `site-packages/conda.pth` file), rather than directly installing into `site-packages`. Sounds like it would make it easier to rebuild while you develop the package without having to reinstall every time.

Here's the relevant blurb I found [in the code base](https://github.com/conda/conda-build/blob/e715fe141133c3844473fea46c596e92d224ef2e/conda_build/develop.py#L28):

> develop mode builds the extensions in place and makes a link to package in site-packages/.